# Where is the exception caught?

Tags: java, exception

I'm reading a friend's note from class, and I'm wondering what's the answer to the question in the comment of the following code?

```
public void withdraw(double amount) { 
        if (amount > balance) { 
            IllegalArgumentException exception1 = new IllegalArgumentException("Amount exceeds balance"); 
            throw exception1; //where caught?? 
        }
        balance = balance - amount;
    }
```

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing what code calls this method. It might never be caught - it might propagate all the way up to the main method and cause the program to exit.

Comment: In the caller of the `withdraw` method?

Comment: @Nambari IllegalArgumentException is unchecked.

Comment: `try { withdraw(amount); } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) { // do stuff with exception }`

Answer (score 4):

IllegalArgumentException is an unchecked Exception, so if you don't catch it somewhere in your program it will go up all the way until it reaches the VM, and execution stops.

with credit to @JBNizet: when your method is invoked from a thread which is NOT the main thread, then that thread will stop, when the exception is thrown. But the main thread will continue its execution.

Answer (score 1):

The exception which you throw from a method is delegated to the method which invoked it, if you don't handle it inside your method. And finally it travels the method invocation hierarchy till the bottom of the stack of your main thread, which is your `main` method. Now, if main method does not handle the exception, then it reaches `JVM` which halts your main thread, and displays the exception occurred as full stack trace.

As @JBNizet pointed out in comment, if your method is invoked from some other thread which is not `main` thread, then that thread will stop, when the exception reaches its `run` method. But the main thread will continue its execution. You can guess it why, as every thread has its own `stack`, so main thread is in a different `stack` than the thread where exception occurred.

Comment: Unless the code is invoked from a thread which is not the main thread, in which case the thread will simply stop.

Comment: @JBNizet. Yeah exactly. Didn't considered the case of multithreading here. But that's a valid point. :)